# RR_4035, ORA-01843: not a valid month ERROR

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, informatica, informatica-powercenter

We are calling one Oracle stored procedure passing one input parameter(id) from Informatica.

While executing the stored procedure directly in oracle, it is getting executed successfully without error.

However, while calling via informatica, it is throwing:

> ORA-01843: not a valid month error with the specific txn id.

We are not getting any error for the error causing id (as per the error log), while executing the stored procedure directly .

Erroneous clause in SP:

```
--------------------------------------------

Stored procedure where clause throwing error while comparing 2- date fields

 

Where NVL ( <date1>, TO_DATE ('01/01/9999', 'MM/DD/YYYY'))

<> NVL (<date2>, TO_DATE ('01/01/9999', 'MM/DD/YYYY'))
```

Comment: can be because of below reasons - 1. the column that you are passing doesnt have the data that oracle SP expects. Pls check the data and data type. Most probably this value is blank 2. The data it passes to Oracle SP is generating some undefined month inside SP. so you need to debug oracle SP using the infa column output. if you share SP definition and mapping input, i can give more idea.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement; the `CREATE TABLE` statements; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data; the code you are using to call the stored procedure directly; the code you are using to call the stored procedure in Informatica. If you don't give us a complete example then we cannot replicate the error.

Comment: If the error is really coming from the line you showed, then that would suggest that `<date1>` and/or `<date2>` are strings, not real dates, and you are relying on implicit conversion and session NLS settings.